# How to wait for dispatch to complete using thunk middleware?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am using redux-thunk and want like to dispatch an action and once that is finished make an api call with part of that updated store.

store.js

```
const middleware = composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk, logger()))
const localStore = loadStore()
const store = createStore(reducer, localStore, middleware)
```

graphActions.js:

First add an Element:

```
export function addElement(element) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({
            type: ADD_ELEMENT,
            payload: element
        })
    }
}
```

Then make api call via different action creator:

```
export function saveElements() {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        let graphId = getState().elements.id
        let elements = getState().elements.elements

        axios.put(Config.config.url + '/graph/' + graphId, {
            'data': JSON.stringify({elements: elements}),
        }).then(() => {
            dispatch({type: SHOW_SUCCESS_SNACKBAR})
        }).catch((err) => {
            dispatch({type: SHOW_ERROR_SNACKBAR})
            dispatch({type: UPDATE_ELEMENTS_REJECTED, payload: err})
        })
    }
}
```

I need to make sure, that addElement() is finished before saveElements(), so that saveElements() accesses the updated store.
I tried the following:

```
export function addElement(element) {
    const promise = (dispatch) => new Promise((resolve) => {
        dispatch({
            type: ADD_ELEMENT,
            payload: element
        })
        resolve()
    })

    return dispatch => {
        promise(dispatch).then(() => {
            saveElements()
        })
    }
}
```

ADD_ELEMENT is dispatched, but the actions within saveElements() are not dispatched, no api call is made.

Comment: Try at minimum returning the promise inside addElement to consume it elsewhere

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Unfortunately, returning the promise(dispatch).then... does not help

Comment: It&#39;s not the promise, you need to return the promises and inner values otherwise you cannot chain it. You need to explicitly return all pieces when using curly braces syntax.

Comment: thanks, I also missed to dispatch saveElements().

Answer (score 0):

I was missing to dispatch saveElements() and returning dispatch(saveElements()).

```
export function addElement(element) {
    const promise = (dispatch) => new Promise((resolve) => {
        dispatch({
            type: ADD_ELEMENT,
            payload: element
        })
        resolve()
    })

    return (dispatch) => {
        return addElements(dispatch).then(() => {
            return dispatch(saveElements())
    })
}
```

UPDATE:

Noticed I can simply do:

```
export function addElement(element)
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: ADD_ELEMENT,
            payload: element
        })

        dispatch(saveElements())
    })
}
```